# Can't compile RIES with MinGW on Win7

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

I'm trying to compile [this program](http://www.mrob.com/pub/ries/ries.c.txt) using MinGW on Windows 7.
On my first try it gave me this error:

```
>gcc -o ries.exe ries.c -lm

ries.c:1582:21: fatal error: stdafx.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I googled for a bit and found out I should remove the `# include "stdafx.h"` line, which I did.

Now it gives me this:

```
C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\cczlkqve.o:ries.c:(.text+0xb9): undefined reference to `asprintf'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Google is now silent... what should I do next?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MinGW uses (AFAIK) the Microsoft C run-time library. I don't think [asprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf) or an equivalent exists in that - although that is odd since he's included stdafx.h for Windows builds anyway, although not in a particularly useful way (it can't AFAICS be used for pre-compiled headers since it's inside an #if)

The simplest fix would be to allocate the buffer yourself, i.e. change

```
char * name_ext;
int nc;
nc = asprintf(&name_ext, "%s.ries", filename);
```

to

```
char name_ext[MAX_PATH];
int nc;
nc = snprintf(name_ext, MAX_PATH, "%s.ries", filename);
```

If MAX_PATH isn't defined (but I think it will be: you've already got stdlib.h) then either define it yourself or just substitute the number 260.